# Install Windows Service Error The inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown The dependency service or group failed to start

Tags: c#, .net, windows

i developed windows service working fine in my computer when i tried install it in `windows server 2008 Standard 32 bit`  it is give me error

The inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown with the fol lowing error message:

> The dependency service or group failed to start.

i checks all way to install the window service, by Batch by installutill and by using installshild every time i got this error log

> Running a transacted installation.
>
> Beginning the Install phase of the installation. See the contents of
>   the log file for the c:\Program Files\H2A\KnittingControlSer
>   vice\Knitting.exe assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   c:\Program Files\H2A\KnittingControlService\Knitting.Inst allLog.
>   Installing assembly 'c:\Program
>   Files\H2A\KnittingControlService\Knitting.exe'. Affected parameters
>   are:
>
> ```
> logtoconsole =
>    logfile = c:\Program Files\H2A\KnittingControlService\Knitting.InstallLog
>    "assemblypath = c:\Program Files\H2A\KnittingControlService\Knitting.exe"
> ```
>
> Installing service Knitting Control Service... Service Knitting
>   Control Service has been successfully installed. Creating EventLog
>   source Knitting Control Service in log Application... An exception
>   occurred in the OnAfterInstall event handler of System.ServiceProce
>   ss.ServiceInstaller. System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start
>   service Knitting Control Service on computer '.'. The inner exception
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown with the fol lowing
>   error message: The dependency service or group failed to start.
>
> An exception occurred during the Install phase.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: An exception occurred in the
>   OnAfterInstall ev ent handler of
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller. The inner exception
>   System.InvalidOperationException was thrown with the followi ng error
>   message: Cannot start service Knitting Control Service on computer
>   '.'. . The inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was
>   thrown with the fol lowing error message: The dependency service or
>   group failed to start.
>
> The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning. See the contents
>   of the log file for the c:\Program Files\H2A\KnittingControlSer
>   vice\Knitting.exe assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   c:\Program Files\H2A\KnittingControlService\Knitting.Inst allLog.
>   Rolling back assembly 'c:\Program
>   Files\H2A\KnittingControlService\Knitting.exe' . Affected parameters
>   are:    logtoconsole =    logfile = c:\Program
>   Files\H2A\KnittingControlService\Knitting.InstallLog    assemblypath =
>   c:\Program Files\H2A\KnittingControlService\Knitting.exe Restoring
>   event log to previous state for source Knitting Control Service.
>   Service Knitting Control Service is being removed from the system...
>   Service Knitting Control Service was successfully removed from the
>   system.
>
> The Rollback phase completed successfully.
>
> The transacted install has completed. The installation failed, and the
>   rollback has been performed."

Comment: Properly formatted the text

Comment: yes i did but the same error still exists

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues in the past and they have often turned out to be permission-related. Are you running your install script as an "Administrator"? (right-click on script -> "Run As Administrator")

Comment: Yes i using Run As Administrator, but every time is give me same error, but how to turn off permission